# How can I use Html.RenderPartial in a master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am writing a master page and I want to render a user control like this:

```
<body>

<% Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl"); %>

</body>
```

In my master page I have this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

On Visual Studio I get a error: HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for "RenderPartial", so I imported the namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html and I don't get that error anymore, but when I run the application I get this error:

Parser Error Message: The directive is missing a 'interface' attribute.

Line 2:  <%@ Implements Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

The version of System.Web.Mvc is 5.2.4

What would be the correct way to use Html.RenderPartial?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
<% Html.Partial("MyUserControl"); %>
```

Instead of

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl"); %>
```

This worked for me.